# Find the nested function.

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given function $$f(x) = \frac{1+x}{x}$$ find the nested function: $$ \underbrace{f\circ f\circ f\circ ...\circ f}$$ the $f$ is there $n$-times.

I've found that $f\circ f = \frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ and that $f\circ f\circ f =\frac{3x+2}{2x+1} $ but there doesn't really seem to be a pattern and I'm finding it hard to find the domain and the equation for the nested function.  (I can see the pattern for functions $f\circ f$ and $f\circ f\circ f$ but it isn't applicable to $f\circ f\circ f\circ f$ and so on...)

Comment: Do a few more. coefficients are adjacent fibonacci numbers.

Comment: You can also prove that @coffeemath is correct by using induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $n^{th}$ composition the composite function is:
$$\frac{(F_{n+2})x+F_{n+1}}{(F_{n+1})x+F_{n}}$$
Where $F_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Finonacci term starting from $0$.

For a proof of the same you can rely on mathematical induction.

The domain is:
$$dom(f)\backslash\{-\frac{F_k}{F_{k+1}}:1\leq k\leq{n}\}$$

Comment: What about the domain though?

Comment: Wouldn't the domain simply be all real numbers except those where the denominator in any of the iterates is zero?

Comment: @Blitzer yes, you are right. But instead of the parental set being the set of all reals, it would be the domain of f, the original function

Comment: @SohamSaha in edit should be = after dom(f) not minus.

Comment: @coffeemath I don’t think so. The part {…} are the values of x you want to remove, since they will give a denominator of 0 at some iteration. And you are removing those values from dom(f), the domain of the original function. This gives you the domain of the composite function. The ‘minus’ is the set difference operator

Comment: @coffemath I am using dom(f) instead of R because the actual domain of the function f is not told in the question

Comment: @SohamSaha If you mean set theoretic minus, maybe that's my concern, since the little horizontal minus to me does not mean set theoretic difference.

Comment: @coffeemath https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement  does say that the notation is ambiguous, but doesn’t our context clarify that? Still, editing my answer.